# jQuery selector does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery selector to hide and unhide some dynamically generated HTML cells. However, it seems like I did not choose the right selector. So, I appreciate if you could give me some suggestions.

The webpage:

1. first ask users to select the number of applications
2. based on users selection, generate two input fields "Application timing", and "Application Date" for each application.
3. There are two options in the "Application timing". If the user chooses "Default", the "Application Date" will disappear.

Problem:
When there are more than three applications, only the last "Application Date" will disappear, not matter where the selection is made. I think it is because I did not use the right selector.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/godhong/JDFcn/6/)

HTML CODE

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="id_NOA">Number of applications:</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <select id="id_NOA" class="valid" name="NOA">
                <option selected="selected" value="">Choose</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_NOA').change(function() {

        var total = $(this).val();
        $('.app_timing').remove();
        $('.app_dates').remove();

        for (var i = 1; i <= total; i++) {

            $('<tr class="app_timing"><th><label for="id_Apt' + i + '">Application timing ' + i + ':</label></th><td><select name="Apt' + i + '" id="id_Apt' + i + '"><option value="" selected="selected">Select an application timing</option><option value="1">Default</option><option value="2">Enter your own</option></select></td></tr>').appendTo('.table')

            $('<tr class="app_dates"><th><label for="id_Date_apt">Application Date ' + i + ':</label></th><td><input readonly="readonly" type="text" name="Date_apt' + i + '" value="MM/DD" id="id_Date_apt' + i + '"/><td></tr>').appendTo('.table')

            $('.app_timing:last').find('select').bind('change', function() {
                if ($(this).val() == '1') {
                    $('.app_dates:last').hide()
                //$('#id_Date_apt' + i).hide() //I tried to use ID selector, but it does not work 
                }

            })
        }
    })


})​
```

Comment: You are specifically selecting the last app_date.  Use `$('.app_dates')` instead of `$('.app_dates:last')` to select all of them.

Comment: As @NickG. said, though you are binding multiple events of the same function in a for loop, think it's best to use it outside a loop.

Comment: @Boltclock: the question is rubbish - `jQuery selector does not work properly`, there really is no question.  There is something that asks for suggestions and something that states a problem.  `Yes it does.` is a perfectly acceptable answer to the title/question

Comment: @vol7ron: my bad for not selecting a proper title, since my experience with web programming is only several weeks. I appreciate if you have a better title.

Comment: @tao.hong: that's understandable, but the problem is that it is not supposed to be a title.  It's supposed to be a question.  My only concern is that at no point throughout your post did you ask a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.app_dates:last').hide()
```

The above line is within the `change` handler and is not executed until the handler fires.  At the time it fires, this will get the last element, which causes the behavior you observed.  You can use the following:

```
$(this).closest("tr").next().hide()
```

Note that this is based on your current html.  A change would require this to change.  It simply hides the next row in the table.

**EDIT:**

While the above answers the question, an overall better approach would be to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).  This will allow you to attach a single handler rather than creating new handlers every time the dropdown is changed.  (Note that I added a class to each select to simplify the selector)

```
$(".table").on("change",".timeSel",function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.val() == '1') {
        $(this).closest("tr").next().hide();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JDFcn/11/

Comment: Thanks James. One question, I can add selectors to the parentheses of next, right?(e.g. next(jQuery selector))

Comment: @tao.hong You can, however all it will not go beyond the immediate next element.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
$('.app_dates:last').hide()
```

with

```
$(this).closest('.app_timing').next().hide()
```

`:last` or using `i` wont work due to the fact that the event will happen after the entire for loop has been iterated through.

Comment: `.app_dates` is not an ancestor of the select.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('.app_timing:last').find('select').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '1') {
        $(this).parents('tr').next('.app_dates').remove();
    }
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JDFcn/9/)**

This will delete the row below the row you change to "default". It travels up the DOM and then back down again to find the row to remove.

Answer (score 0):

When your function is called, it tries to access the variable *i* which has been left incremented to 1 more than the number you chose in the top drop down so you can't use that. Your selector will never return anything.

I would suggest pulling the value for *i* out of the id property of **this** which is available in the anonymous function.

maybe something like this:

```
var idx = this.id.substring(6);   // You may want something fancier here
$('#app_dates' + idx).hide();
```

When I make that change in your jsFiddle, I can get the first one to disappear.